# How can I put cursor back to netrw window after finish editing

Tags: vim, netrw

After open a file in my `gvim`, it looks like this

```
________________________
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|  NETRW    |  EDITOR  |
|           |          |
|           |          |
|           |          |
------------------------
```

By default cursor will be in the editor window when the file is open up, which is good, but how can i get back to `netRw` window after finish editing so I can choose or open other files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do `<C-w>h` or `<C-w><Left>` to move to the left window or `<C-w>p` to move to the previous window or `<C-w>w` to cycle between windows.

See `:help window-move-cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following four maps and the shift-up, etc arrow keys to change windows.  Place these in your .vimrc file.

```
nmap <s-down>  <c-w>j
nmap <s-up>    <c-w>k
nmap <s-left>  <c-w>h
nmap <s-right> <c-w>l
```